# when I convert from html to PDF the line break is not coming in the converted PDF page as I can see in the HTML page

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf

I have searched everywhere, but I found answers regarding how to give line break in html page. But my problem is not that, I am getting the proper line breaks in the HTML page.But when the conversion is done from HTML to PDF, the information displays as a paragraph in the PDF page and not as a list. I need to display it as list.

Here is my angular code for converting form html to pdf

```
crmMain.directive('exportToPdf', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            elemId: '@'
        },
        template: '<button data-ng-click="exportToPdf()" style="text-
        decoration: none;background - color: green;color: white;
        " 
        class = "btn" > Export to PDF < /button>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
             scope.exportToPdf = function() {
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                console.log('elemId 12312321', scope.elemId);
                doc.fromHTML(
                    document.getElementById(scope.elemId).innerHTML, 15, 15, {
                        'width': 170,
                    });
                doc.save(scope.elemId + '.pdf');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And I have used the below code for displaying the details in HTML page

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="{{client.company_name}}" style="width:100%;color: black;border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 22px;border:none;font-weight: 
                         bold">
            <h3 style="font-weight: 700;padding: 
                          0px;margin:0px;">Details of '{{client.company_name}}'</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-weight: bold;margin-
                            bottom:20px;">Customer Name</span>
            <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span>{{client.customer_name}}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">Customer 
                          Email</span>
            <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span>{{client.customer_email}}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">Address</span>
            <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span>{{client.address_1}},{{client.address_2}},{{client.address_3}}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">City</span>
            <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span>{{client.city}}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">State</span>
            <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span>{{client.state}}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">Country</span>
            <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span>{{client.country}}</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **outerHTML:** when you want print the html target you do not need the `innerHtml`, use `outerHTML` to get the html effects too like `class`, `style` or ...

```
doc.fromHTML(
  document.getElementById(scope.elemId).outerHTML, 15, 15, {
       'width': 170,
});
```

**This sample miss `jspdf` library** *run it in your local*

Result will be like this image

[image: Result be like this]

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('exportToPdf', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      elemId: '@'
    },
    template: '<button data-ng-click="exportToPdf()" style="text-decoration: none;background-color: green;color: white;" class="btn" > Export to PDF</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.exportToPdf = function() {

        var doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.fromHTML(
          document.getElementById(scope.elemId).outerHTML, 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
          });

        doc.save(scope.elemId + '.pdf');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <export-to-pdf elem-id="topdf"></export-to-pdf>

  <table class="table table-hover" id="topdf" style="width:100%;color: black;border:none;">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 22px;border:none;font-weight:
                     bold">
        <h3 style="font-weight: 700;padding:
                      0px;margin:0px;">
          Details of Test
        </h3>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <span style="font-weight: bold;margin-
                        bottom:20px;">Customer Name</span>
        <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span>Name</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">
                        Customer
                        Email
                    </span>
        <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span>Email</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Address</span>
        <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span>address_1, address_2, address_3</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">City</span>
        <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span>city</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">State</span>
        <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span>state</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Country</span>
        <span> &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span>country</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: let i put my sample

Comment: I don't see any other differences between my code and your sample except "outerHTML", I have tried putting "outherHTML",  but the result is same.

Comment: I am getting the same output as you are getting. But it's not in correct format, I need to display in a proper format

Answer (score 0):

Why not explore using the `page-break-after` CSS property.

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp) for further information.